# Preventing window deletion in angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have a single window that I'm moving about the map on marker click (1000s of markers). It all works fine until I press the 'x' to close the window, which seems to delete the info window from the dom instead of just hiding it. I see there's a closeClick paramater, but I'm not sure what this does and can't seem to connect it to a function in order to override the deleton.

Here's the markup:

```
<google-map
 id="map-canvas"
 draggable="true"
 bounds="map.bounds"
 center="map.center"
 zoom="map.zoom"
 options="map.options"
 events="map.events"
 zoom="map.zoom">
    <window 
     show="map.infoWindow.show"
     coords="map.infoWindow.coords"
     closeClick="map.infoWindow.close" ng-cloak>
        Testing!
    </window>
    <markers
     models="map.mountains"
     coords="'self'"
     icon="'icon'"
     click="'onClicked'"
     options="'options'"
     doCluster="false">
   </markers>
</google-map>
```

And here's [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xVCv.png) of the window and 'x' button:

How can I prevent the window from being deleted and just hide it instead?

Or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly confident adding/removing from DOM is google-maps functionality, not angular-google-maps functionality. Test out your scenario on a vanilla google-maps instance and see if the same behavior is present. If so, there's not much that can be done about it.

The closeClick event is fired when the "x" on the window is clicked. You hook up to it by adding something like `closeClick="scopeFunction()"`. This will not likely help your scenario.

EDIT: A better way to get only one window open at a time is to use only one window object, bind it to a "currentMarker" on scope and in the onclick of the markers just change "currentMarker" to reflect the currently selected marker. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you're right.

I want to create an info window at a marker's location when I click on said marker. I want to be able to close and reopen the info window. I want to be able to click on another marker and have the info window appear at the new marker. As I have several hundred markers at once, and only ever want to display one info window, I don't want to use the <windows> directive (also it crashes the browser, but that's another story).

At the moment, it does all of the above, but when I close the info window then I lose it forever.

Comment: It'd be greatly helpful if you could file a ticket about the browser crash, with a plnkr demonstrating the issue, over at https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues .

Comment: With regards to your edit - this wouldn't let me close the marker would it? How can I achieve this but still be allowed to press the 'x'? How do I programatically create info windows..? Can I call the google maps API directly?

Comment: If you create just a single window, there is no need to programmatically create them. If you need to programmatically create them, use an ng-repeat on <window> then add and remove from the list you repeat over. The edit would allow you to close the marker, by setting showWindow bool that you are using.